# How to Print the output of a function using console.log (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

The following code is meant print the namestring with a name. however, it's not correct.

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Hi, I am" + " " + name.

}
nameString("Amir")
console.log(nameString)
```

What am I not implementing/doing wrong that stops it from displaying the string as well as a name? thanks.

Comment: `console.log(nameString("Amir"))`

Comment: You have to actually return the result of the function somewhere, just calling it isn't enough!

Comment: `nameString` is function definition, this will print function. `nameString()` will execute the function, this will print the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First mistake in your code is in the line

```
 return "Hi, I am" + " " + name.
```

remove fullstop or just concatenate it as below

```
 return "Hi, I am" + " " + name+"."
```

and then write

```
console.log(nameString("Amir"));
```

check it here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLLp8/)

Comment: the fullstop was throwing the entire code off, thanks for pointing it out, and now it's fixed. Beginners mistake that i will remember for next time, thanks again!

Comment: I still have to wait a few minutes, before I can accept an answer. I'll do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to call that function.

```
console.log(nameString("Amir"));
```

If you will say `console.log(nameString)` it will just print the value of varibale `nameString` which is a `function`.

There is a `.` in your function in last of `return` statement, remove that.

Comment: thank you as well for pointing out the full stop in the return statement, beginners mistake and it won't happen again. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(nameString())
```

just forgot to **CALL** the function.
and pass params

```
console.log(nameString('anyString'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`nameString` is a method and you are not passing argument to it

```
console.log(nameString("Amir"));
```

or

```
var str=nameString("Amir");
console.log(str);
```

and also remove `.`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nameString = function(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " + name
  nameString("Sophie");
}
console.log(nameString("Sophie"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal, which makes the code more readable and makes your job easier. You don't have to think about spaces and there are fewer inverted commas.

```
var nameString = function (name) {
  return `Hi, I'm ${name}.`;
};
nameString("Amir");
console.log(nameString("Amir"));
```